# Dockerized ASP.NET Core app not creating folder

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core

I've created Dockerfile for ASP.NET Core app. It is creating folder for logs when running locally without Docker - sadly it is not doing the same with Docker.

Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build-env

WORKDIR /app

COPY . ./

RUN dotnet restore

RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build-env /app/IPA.Web/out .

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT dotnet IPA.Web.dll --launch-profile Development
```

I am creating folder with

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("Logs");
```

I want it to create a folder inside running docker image with path

```
/app/Logs
```

Edit:

After comment from @DazWilkin I've tried to create folder manually - sadly it didn't work as well.

What is more, I'm not getting any errors from app.

To create logs inside Logs directory I'm using

```
  Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions
```

Comment: Wouldnt whatever folder it creates live on the virtualized instance?  Not on your actual file system?

Comment: Actually I want it to create it on the virtualized instance - with this I can manage

Comment: You say that it is not creating the directory in the container but you don't explain why. Why do you think the directory is not being created? Do you get an error? It may (!?) be that the app assumes the directory exists and won't create it if it doesn't. If so, you may wish to add a line after perhaps "WORKDIR" of the form "RUN mkdir -p /app/Logs" and see whether that helps.

Comment: Logging into the container image is a bad practice. When you upgrade your application, all the logs are lost (since a new container is created and new filesystem layer is added when you run it). Best practice is to mount an volume into your container, that way the logs would be written to the volume. When you deploy a new version of your application and mount the same volume back to it, your logs will remain

Comment: @Tseng - I am aware of good practices while working with Docker, but when the directory is not created in container it won't be in mounted volume either.